# Where did De Morgan write the laws that are named for him?

Tags: logic, history-of-logic

I've been reading through De Morgan's [Formal Logic](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_HscAAAAAMAAJ/page/n207/mode/2up). The book seems more of a combination of an introduction to logic and a grab bag of De Morgan's ideas than a formal system, but I can see why some of them are influential, especially his introduction of quantification as a kind of operator.

What I can't find in there are the laws De Morgan is most famous for, the laws that are named for him (even though he wasn't the first to observe them):

```
~(P & Q) <=> ~P | ~Q
~(P | Q) <=> ~P & ~Q
```

Surprisingly, neither Wikipedia nor the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy states where De Morgan wrote this, or even if it is in *Formal Logic* or some other work. It seems that he would have have to have read Boole to be thinking of AND and OR like operations this way, but Boole's *The Mathematical Analysis of Logic* came out the same year, so in that case it would have to have been in a later work.

Alternately, are what we call De Morgan's laws a symbolic interpretation of an idea he expressed very differently in *Formal Logic* as rules about quantification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Formal Logic (1847)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Formal_Logic/rlq9REUSdWQC), page 116:

> The contrary of PQR is p,q,r. [...] In contraries, conjunction and disjunction change places.

And see A.De Morgan's [On the Syllogism III (1858)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/On_the_Syllogism/t02wDwAAQBAJ?gbpv=1), page 182:

> The contrary of an aggregate is the compound of the contraries of the aggregants: the contrary of a compound is the aggregate of the contraries of the components. Thus (A,B) and AB have ab and (a.b) for contraries.

A more "modern" symbolic formulation is present into C.S.Perice, [On the Algebra of Logic: A Contribution to the Philosophy of Notation (1885)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2369451?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), page 191:

> **"overline"(x+y)= "overline (x) "overline"(y)**.